# Ansible AWX: trigger python script using Ansible playbook when .yml and .py files are located in Github

Tags: python, github, ansible-awx

I am starting to integrate AWX into our environment and would like to move & schedule some python scripts there, but I am facing issue to trigger python script using Ansible playbook. There is .YML and .PY located in the same Github repository & directory. I trigger Ansible playbook which initiates python script as per below 2 lines (there is more of the code of course) and everything completes OK, but script is not triggered. Previously all python scripts were located on the host locally and scheduled via windows task scheduler.

**CODE:**

```
- name: Checking for duplicate clients

  script: duplicate_clients.py
```

Seems that Python script on the windows host is even not started, as I do not see python started in the task manager.

**DEBUG**:

```
    <server_XXX> PUT "/runner/project/MISC/duplicate_clients.py" TO "C:\Users\C017317\AppData\Local\Temp\ansible-tmp-1656571782.4292357-31-141461256091413\duplicate_clients.py"
EXEC (via pipeline wrapper)
EXEC (via pipeline wrapper)
changed: [server_XXX] => {
    "changed": true,
    "rc": 0,
    "stderr": "#< CLIXML<Objs Version=\"1.1.0.1\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04\"><Obj S=\"progress\" RefId=\"0\"><TN RefId=\"0\"><T>System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject</T><T>System.Object</T></TN><MS><I64 N=\"SourceId\">1</I64><PR N=\"Record\"><AV>Preparing modules for first use.</AV><AI>0</AI><Nil /><PI>-1</PI><PC>-1</PC><T>Completed</T><SR>-1</SR><SD> </SD></PR></MS></Obj></Objs>",
    "stderr_lines": [
        "#< CLIXML<Objs Version=\"1.1.0.1\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04\"><Obj S=\"progress\" RefId=\"0\"><TN RefId=\"0\"><T>System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject</T><T>System.Object</T></TN><MS><I64 N=\"SourceId\">1</I64><PR N=\"Record\"><AV>Preparing modules for first use.</AV><AI>0</AI><Nil /><PI>-1</PI><PC>-1</PC><T>Completed</T><SR>-1</SR><SD> </SD></PR></MS></Obj></Objs>"
3…
META: ran handlers
```

However, I have tried a different approach to start python script (as I am not sure how exactly it should be done when script is located on Github).

**CODE:**

```
- name: Checking for duplicate clients
command: py -3 duplicate_clients.py
```

**DEBUG**

```
> EXEC (via pipeline wrapper)
Using module file /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible/modules/command.py
Pipelining is enabled.
EXEC (via pipeline wrapper)
[WARNING]: No python interpreters found for host
server_XXX (tried ['python3.10', 'python3.9',
'python3.8', 'python3.7', 'python3.6', 'python3.5', '/usr/bin/python3',
'/usr/libexec/platform-python', 'python2.7', 'python2.6', '/usr/bin/python',
'python'])
fatal: [server_XXX]: FAILED! => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    },
    "changed": false,
```

Seems it is looking python on a linux path, though the target host is a windows.

The python script here is not an issue, as it is simply creating a test file. Running script locally completes with RC=0.

Comment: _but script is not triggered_ > what makes you say that? Have you tried registering its output and doing a `debug` on it?

Comment: So your python script is indeed run, but it is errororing with what you can see in the `stderr` property of the debug. Now the question is what is in that Python script? Are you sure you are exiting it properly?

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε, yes I did run it locally on the target host and it works with no issues. The script is for testing, so it simply creates a file in C:\temp\

Comment: Are you 100% sure this does not exit with an error code? The content of the error line spitted by it really seems to me like what you intended to output in your test file.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε yes, 100% sure. Cannot add the photo in my post, so here is the screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/QJOnc7N

Comment: You are not running the same script, did you realise?

Answer (score 0):

So the issue has been resolved by providing python executable path.

```
- name: Checking for duplicate clients
  script: create_file.py
  args: 
    executable: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\python.exe"'
```